# Two routes to the same network - different priority

Tags: networking, openbsd

I'm trying to decide about the most suitable configuration for my server with two external interfaces, both getting an external IP number from an ISP over DHCP. This is so I can host different services on different IPs. The addresses will *most likely* reside in the same network, potentially causing some headache with my routing.

The easiest scenario is simply to assign a different [priority](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-6.1/ifconfig.8) to each network interface, having one interface as "primary", to which everything is routed by default. Since I am not interested in load-balancing or fail-over, this should work.

```
ifconfig em0 priority 0
ifconfig em2 priority 10
```

I have simulated the scenario using a local DHCP server, and it seems to work well. The [routing table](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-6.1/route.8) looks like this after automatic configuration over DHCP:

```
# route -n show -inet
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags   Refs      Use   Mtu  Prio Iface
default            10.0.0.1           UGS        0        0     -     8 em0
224/4              127.0.0.1          URS        0        0 32768     8 lo0
10.0.0/24          10.0.0.2           UCn        1       13     -     4 em0
10.0.0/24          10.0.0.3           UCn        0        0     -    14 em2
10.0.0.1           xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:01  UHLch      1       12     -     3 em0
10.0.0.2           xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:02  UHLl       0        0     -     1 em0
10.0.0.3           xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:03  UHLl       0        3     -     1 em2
10.0.0.255         10.0.0.2           UHPb       0        0     -     1 em0
10.0.0.255         10.0.0.3           UHPb       0        0     -     1 em2
127/8              127.0.0.1          UGRS       0        0 32768     8 lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UHhl       1        2 32768     1 lo0
```

There is only one default exit through my gateway, and the conflicting route `10.0.0/24` has different priorities, so only one way should be used unless explicitly requested.

According to all my tests, this works well. In particular:

- Services on the server listening to both IPs can be reached using either IP.
- Services listening on either one interface can only be reached on that interface.
- When pinging a host from the server I can select an outgoing interface. This works as expected.

But I'm still worried and I have two questions in particular:

#### Should I delete the extra route to my network?

I have two routes to `10.0.0/24`. The "Use" counter for the latter never increments, and my network seems to work even if I delete the one for `em2`.

```
10.0.0/24          10.0.0.2           UCn        1       13     -     4 em0
10.0.0/24          10.0.0.3           UCn        0        0     -    14 em2
```

Is the second route even necessary? If not, does it do any harm?

#### Do I need two broadcasts for the same network?

Each interface also sets up its own broadcast to the same network.

```
10.0.0.255         10.0.0.2           UHPb       0        0     -     1 em0
10.0.0.255         10.0.0.3           UHPb       0        0     -     1 em2
```

The same question here: Are both necessary, and if not, is it harmful? I could easily imagine that each interface must have an entry in the table, but I'm afraid I don't know enough about this. I don't see any weird things going on in my LAN.

---

#### ...hold on

After running with this setup for a while, the network stopped working. Checking the logs, I see this:

```
arp: attempt to add entry for 10.0.0.1 on em0 by xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx on em2
arpresolve: 10.0.0.1: route contains no arp information
arpresolve: 10.0.0.1: route contains no arp information
arpresolve: 10.0.0.1: route contains no arp information
...
```

Apparently *something* in the setup has to change. I'm still not sure what.